# Is it possible, given a target temperature, to create an alloy that melts at precisely that temperature?

Tags: melting-point, alloy

Assuming the target melting points are between the melting points of mercury and tungsten, is it possible, given a target temperature, to create an alloy (or compound) composition that has a direct (say eutectic) transformation to liquid at +/- one degree of the target temperature?

If yes, is there a method for identifying the elements to use based on the target temperature?

Comment: That is actually a hard question to answer properly. Do you mean an alloy (or compound) composition that has a direct (say eutectic) transformation to the liquid?

Comment: The answer hinges on how you define "precisely". Melt within +/- 5 degrees yes. All melt within +/- 0.01 degree no. So you'd have to make a 80/20 by weight mixture of the metals which by the phase diagram should melt at temperature T. You then melt the metals and quickly quench the melt. The composition will be almost homogeneous, but not absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question based on your comments

Comment: Probably no. Alloys melt at precise temperature in two cases: eutectics and intermetallics.  Given number of metals it is reasonable to expect that *some* eutectic or intermetallic would melt quite close to required temperature. But identifying such composition is another matter entirely.

Comment: You can identify materials (alloys and many others) with certain physical characteristics (such as melting point within a temperature range) and see what emerges from a database - I use [Matweb](www.matweb.com) for this sort of thing on occasion. I entered the temperature range of -38.83 $^{\circ}$C to 3422 $^{\circ}$C and got 619 hits under the "Solder/Braze Alloy" category. I now know that 97% lead, 2.5% tin, and 0.5% silver solder melts between 303-310 $^{\circ}$C, with the lower number corresponding to the solidus and the higher one to the liquidus. Might be of help to you...

Comment: The other facet to this is do you want the metal to melt/solidify at that temperature or just melt once at that temperature. // !@#$%^& theoretical rabbit holes.

Comment: Adding to the above - from one eutectic point one may be able to add other elements to move the eutectic point around. This, of course, rapidly becomes quite complex. (As I type this I'm also calculating the Al-La phase diagram. So the thermodynamics of phase transitions are kind of up my alley.) I'll also add that many intermetallics do transform directly to the liquid.

Comment: What do you mean by create? If experiments allowed, then sure, yes.

Comment: thanks all! If anyone wants to venture an answer I'd accept it. Based on your comments it sounds like it's possible but there's no straight line from target temp to composition parts.

Comment: If you open the question up to more than just metals the answer is likely yes, otherwise, no